# How to Customize PDF file content That open by using Action_View

Tags: android, actionview, pdf-reader, pdf-rendering

Good Morning,

I have Stuck in a strange problem. I want to open PDF file in android...and i succeeded in two
ways

```
1)-->First Using API (But that is damn slow)
```

2)-->Second Using ACTION_VIEW.It work on phone that has Quick Office
 Code is

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/videosadoce.pdf");

     if (file.exists()) {
         Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         try {
             startActivity(intent);
         } 
         catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
             Toast.makeText(MyPdfViewer.this, 
                 "No Application Available to View PDF", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
```

Now i want to customize that view start by default activity.I want to add some animation 
to give effect of page open like book while i am navigating PDF file pages.
So how to customize that pre-define view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize any animation to the third party application, which you launched by your application to view your pdf document. The only way you can achieve this is by integrating any Open Source PDF project and customize it as you want.

Comment: But as i have mention earlier that these are extreme slow.And take aprrox 2 minute in between navigation.

Comment: Those using only java, they are slow and if after a particular zoom they will also send Exception of VMBudget exceeds, I think there are few projects that uses Native Codes also, try your luck with them, they are bit faster.

Comment: Can you give me some reference link that used native code.BTW one upvote for your time